# How to deal with hierachical relations and comparisons in XPath and XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to use XSL to extract information from XML document and present it in an HTML page.
Firstly, the sample structure of the XML:

```
<warehouses>
   <warehouse>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>Florida</name>
      <address>
         <country>US</country>
      </address>
      <items>
         <item>
            <id>1</id>
            <qty>30</qty>
            <name>coke</name>
         </item>
         <item>
            <id>2</id>
            <qty>40</qty>
            <name>pie</name>
         </item>
         .........   # more <item> not being presented like Orange
      </items>
   </warehouse>
   ......   # more <warehouse> located in various countries not being presented
</warehouses>
```

Basically, there are many different `<warehouse>` under the label `<warehouses>` and there are many `<item>` in `<items>`.

What I'm doing now is to present the the names of the warehouses in US or CA **and** the name of the item(s) available with the largest quantity **compared to all items in that specific warehouse**. The output is a HTML table. Like:

```
|Florida           |    Orange    |
|British Columbia  |  Canada Dry  |
```

Note: The XML orders the `<item>` according to each item's id, not quantity. Therefore though only Coke and Pie are printed here simply because of the space limit, there are many other stuffs like Orange with various quantity not being presented.

Currently I'm able to present the country part, but unable to present the product name. Specifically, no output presented in the second column.

```
|Florida           |       |
|British Columbia  |       |
```

Since the XML is a given file without bugs, it should due to wrong XSL.

My XSL code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <table border="1">
<xsl:apply-templates select="/warehouses/warehouse[address/country='US' or address/country='Canada']"/><br />
</table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
 
<xsl:template match="/warehouses/warehouse[address/country='US' or address/country='Canada']">
<tr>  
<td>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/><br/>
</td>
<td>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="items"/>
  </td>
</tr>
</xsl:template>
 
<xsl:template match="name">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
 
<xsl:template match="items">
  <xsl:value-of select="self/item[qty=max(/parent::*/item/qty)]/name"/><br />
</xsl:template>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I believe it's essentially because of my redundant and wrong XPath presented under `<xsl:template match="items">`, since:

1. It involves various parent and child nodes like `<items>`,`<item>`,`<qty>`.
2. I think maybe even the `max()` function is not being used in a right way...

Would somebody help me, many thanks!

Comment: Please make your sample input and your sample output match. Currently you have items named `coke` and `pie` in your XML, but in your table it's `Orange` and `Canada Dry`. This makes it harder to follow what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @Tomalak, sorry about the inconvenience. Due to the space limit, I just sketched the structure. Pie and Coke are presented here simply because the <item> labels are ordered by ids, not quantity. While their ids are 1 and 2, they don't necessarily match the products with the largest and 2nd largest quantity. There are many other items with different quantities not being presented here. I've re-edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not asking you to write more explanations, I'm asking you to make sure that the terms `Orange` and `Canada Dry` and `Florida` and `British Columbia` occur in your sample XML in such a way that the table you show fits the XML you show. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Your question is tagged as both `xslt-1.0` and `xpath-2.0` which makes no sense. Which XSLT processor will you be using?

Answer (score 0):

> the name of the item(s) available with the largest quantity compared to all items in that specific warehouse

We could say that this is the `<item>` for which there is no `<item>` under the same parent that has a smaller `<qty>`, or in XPath `items/item[not(qty &lt; ../item/qty)]`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="warehouses/warehouse[address/country[.='US' or .='Canada']]"/>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
   
  <xsl:template match="warehouse">
    <tr>  
      <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="(items/item[not(qty &lt; ../item/qty)])[1]/name" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
   
  <xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Since there always could be two items with the same `<qty>`, in which case both would be printed, I'm explicitly limiting it to the first one above.

The `<xsl:template match="name">` runs for both `<warehouse>` name and `<item>` name.

Output for your sample is

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Florida</td>
        <td>pie</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```